Exploring Nuclear Fusion with Hydrogen, Ammonia, and Uranium
Would adding liquid nitrogen to hydrogen and breaking its covalent bonds with the laser you're already using for nuclear fusion, produce more energy? As it starts off freezing and gets hotter, it also increases the power wield at second point when it turns into ammonia and makes the hydrogen produce more power through nuclear fusion. So the only spent would be the laser, and the hydrogen would burn hotter thanks to the ammonia. 
Bearing in mind I figured this out with about 15 minutes of research, the laser will be heating up the hydrogen at the same time. Not that I know much yet about it, but uranium as well. Both hydrogen and ammonia will react with uranium while it is in a catalytic reaction to make it more stable. Using hot and cold to cause the uranium to react and get hotter inside the core produces more thermal reaction for the process. 
As I said, I'm not fully there, but the whole thing is just to add stuff to make it more (probably wrong word, but to make it more explosive) and add other stuff to stop it from exploding. For instance, the mixing of ammonia mixed with the uranium will produce ammonia diurante. Could this lead us making energy at the same time as fuel? So, you could use the ammonia to ignite the hydrogen in small amounts safely and use the rest to start making fuel. Plus, after the ignition, you will have a supply of water and nitrogen left over from the the reaction.
It's just a matter of what to do after ignition with the nitrogen, water and uranium. I'm not too sure on that part yet, so I guess the three would mix and carry on the reaction if you turned the uranium into uranium deuteride. The three would explode into power, but I have no clue how to contain that reaction, especially with all the leftover gases. I guess by using manganese to mix nitrogen with the hydrogen, as well as lithium to lower the required heat/power, you could produce more energy in whole. Then, with hydrogen and ammonia, recreate the reaction, creating an infinite amount of power from a limited supply.

I'm sorry, but this as currently written is virtually unintelligible. Please rewrite so it doesn't read like a stream of consciousness

Editing it was pointless. "Don't polish turds."

@Mithoron well I just formatted it because I thought I can, I would reconsider from now on
